# word game with buttons with functional react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state, buttonclick, react-functional-component

[image: pcture]

**Set of buttons:**

In this case the player has 6 moves, as the player clicks on the buttons his choices appear on the screen. There is only one right combination, which are six buttons (True) and two wrong ones (False), after the player chooses his 6 buttons and must click on the button (check) to check if the game is right.
If you are right, a text field should appear, saying you got it right or one saying you got it wrong to try again.

**Problems:**

1. When I click on the first button, the counter does not, working only on the next click.
2. How do I make a check to see if the sequence is correct? Remembering that if you have a false button in your sequence of 6 buttons it is wrong, for it to be correct the sequence must be 6 buttons true.
3. Does the restart button refresh the browser, is there another option to reset everything, and return to the initial state?

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-brown-49ivl)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In each button you are handling the click using two different events `onClick` and `onMouseDown`
Checking the sequence if correct by creating an array of objects, each object will be a button with unique id. You need to count number of true clicked buttons.
We need to restart the game using `react` not `Javascript BOM`, set the `buttons` and `count` to their initial states will reset the game.

Here's the complete working code

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useState } from "react";

// We need to loop over this array to render buttons and answeres
// Id : to handle click on target button
// isRight : weather the answer is right or wrong
// clicked: weather button clicked or not
const initialState = [
  { id: 1, isRight: true, label: "True 1", clicked: false },
  { id: 2, isRight: true, label: "True 2", clicked: false },
  { id: 3, isRight: true, label: "True 3", clicked: false },
  { id: 4, isRight: true, label: "True 4", clicked: false },
  { id: 5, isRight: true, label: "True 5", clicked: false },
  { id: 6, isRight: true, label: "True 6", clicked: false },
  { id: 7, isRight: false, label: "False 7", clicked: false },
  { id: 8, isRight: false, label: "False 8", clicked: false }
];

export default function App() {
  // Button Restart refresh Page
  // reset counter and count to their inital states will reset the game
  function resetGame() {
    setButtons(initialState);
    setCount(6);
    setCorrect(null);
  }

  const [buttons, setButtons] = useState(initialState);

  // Counter
  const [count, setCount] = useState(6);
  const [correct, setCorrect] = useState(null);

  // Click handler will handle both count and buttons changes
  const buttonClickHandler = (id) => {
    if (count === 0) {
      return;
    }
    setCount(count - 1);
   // Update an array of objects
    setButtons(
      buttons.map((item) =>
        item.id === id ? { ...item, clicked: !item.clicked } : item
      )
    );
  };

  // We are counting the clicked buttons which have a property isRight : true
  const checkIfCorrect = () => {
    let correct = buttons.filter(
      (item) => item.clicked === true && item.isRight === true
    ).length;
    if (correct === 6) {
      setCorrect(true)
    } else {
      setCorrect(false)
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <button onClick={resetGame} refresh="true">
          RestartNew
        </button>
        <h3>Chances: 6</h3>
        {count}
      </div>

      <div>
        <h2>Answers</h2>
        {buttons.map(
          (button) =>
            button.clicked && <button key={button.id}>{button.label}</button>
        )}
      </div>
      <h2>Buttons Questions!</h2>
      {/* Question buttons */}
      {buttons.map((button) => (
        <button key={button.id} onClick={() => buttonClickHandler(button.id)}>
          {button.label}
        </button>
      ))}

      <br />
      <br />
      <h2>Checker</h2>
      <button onClick={() => checkIfCorrect()}>Check Answers</button>
      <br />
      <br />
      // Check correct and render your components
      {correct != null && correct && <div>correct</div>}
      {correct != null && !correct && <div>Wrong</div>}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Working Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-euler-k6ebn?file=/src/App.js)

I'm Sorry for My Bad English ^_^

Comment: First of all, I would like to thank you that your code is really fantastic, simple and very intuitive. I would like to know if it is possible to put a component instead of an alert in the answer ... And your English is very good.

Comment: You are welcome. Updated the answer with `setCorrect` and render JSX when the `correct` is changed.

Comment: Is it possible to leave the face without appearing in the initial state? Would it be possible to make it appear only with the check button being triggered? I tried to create another usestate and used else if for that but it didn't work out very well.

Comment: set the initial state of `correct` to `null`, then in JSX check if correct is null before checking it's true of false. See the uodate

Comment: Is there any option to style each button by placing the css inside each array?